# Data Structure - Inserting/Updating into ordered list

Tags: data-structures, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook api to retrieve a list of a user's photos. I'm using this to work out the user's close friends by seeing who has been tagged the most in the user's photos. So what I have the list of the tagged users (there will be duplicates). What I want to do is go through each tag and insert the user into a data structure. If the user is already there I want to increase that user's count by one. At the end I want the list ordered so I can 'rank' the friends. What data structure will be best for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

Use an [associative container.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) Map from UserId to user's count. Keep adding new users, and updating the user's count as you process more data.

Step2:

Copy all the users to another associative container, Now the key should be a [pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/)(user's count, UserId).

You can now iterate over the 2nd container and have your items in order.

If you're using C++, you can use [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) for step 1, and [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) for step 2.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm using PHP, will this affect either steps?

Comment: @user973758: I don't know if PHP supports composite types as keys. If not, for step 2, you can use a multimap and map the user's count to the userId, or use a map from the user's count to an array of userIds